# Impact of using select with blocking and non-blocking sockets

Tags: c, network-programming, nonblocking, select-function

How will my program differ in behavior if I use non-blocking sockets with a select() call as opposed to using blocking sockets with a select() call?

Answer (score 7):

The `select` polling will not behave differently, only the receive/send functionality will differ between blocking/non-blocking sockets.

Comment: So it does not make sense to use blocking sockets with a select call , right? Or is there a use case for this?

Answer (score 4):

`select()` won't behave differently. `read()`, `write()`, `accept()` and other I/O functions will -- they will never block on non-blocking sockets, while they *might* block *even* if `select()` tells they would not, although this is somewhat rare.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5352634/259543

Not sure whether this behavior is allowed by POSIX, though.