# Windows non-cancellation mode of a thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Do Windows support the API to set the cancellation and non-cancellation mode as we do in LINUX with  following functions.
pthread_setcancelstate
pthread_setcanceltype

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988275/windows-api-similar-to-pthread-cancel

Answer (score 1):

download [pthread_w32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/)

and add the lib file path in your project or use

```
#pragma comment(lib, "pthreadVC2.lib")
```

then copy the pthread*.dll to your system path,

and in your code, you can write

```
#include <pthread.h>
```